# To lint on the client, or the server?

Tags: continuous-integration, automation, pull-requests

I am debating two strategies for setting up a linter for my team's github repository.  Is strategy #1 standard practice, or not?

#1 - Set up a pre-commit hook that runs the linter

#2 - My team will manually run the linter on external Pull Requests

- #1 puts more responsibility on the contributor because they need to install and run our linter.  An argument against this is that we may get more external contributors if they don't need to worry about this step.  IE - Make it easy, and we will get more contributors.
- #2 relies on my team to pull, branch, lint, push, and then make a new PR for every external contribution.  While it's easier for the submitter, I think this task is best suited for automation. IE - the contributor should submit linted code, which we test and accept/reject with our CI infrastructure.

I prefer #1.  Is this workflow more typical than #2, and why?

Comment: Personally, neither - I can't think of any reason to treat lint differently to unit tests or other similar checks, so I would include a step in the CI pipeline and look for everything to be green before taking time to look at a PR.

Comment: I think you might actually agree with #1 then.  The contributor should perform unit tests, linting, and similar checks themselves.  The CI pipeline will verify that this has been done, and then a code review can proceed.

Comment: Well yes to that part, but no to the pre-commit hook.  I sometimes find it useful to commit code into a local repo which doesn't pass quality checks or maybe doesn't even build at all.  That could be for investigation or debugging, or maybe even just to commit and leave for a while then come back to fix everything later, or maybe test/prototype code which I have no intention of ever merging.   As long as the CI pipeline can check everything's green before a PR then I think a commit hook could be an optional thing for some developers if they'd like it, but I wouldn't make it mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because people (definitly includes me) have the tendency to focus on "delivering the feature", they tend to sometimes forget the quality assurance steps. Therefor i add the linting always to the commit process, to ensure that only code is commited that follow the rules.

I would also add the linting into the CI pipeline. As a last line of defense, just to be sure.

If you do not have a CI pipeline, then i would definitly manually lint all incoming PR´s, just to be on the safe side, because i can´t know if the pre-commit hook was active and executed on the dev´s machine when he/she commited the code.

Comment: `I would also add the linting into the CI pipeline. As a last line of defense, just to be sure`

I think that linting should be a test on our CI pipeline.  If the submitter did not lint, their PR will fail the test.


I don't think that our CI pipeline should lint the code, and submit the linted changes as a new branch.